# Ошибка Graph returned an error: Invalid appsecret_proof provided in the API argument

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-api, facebook-graph-api

Код публикации сообщения на стенке пользователя почти из оф. документации facebook, вписал app_id, app_secret и token, но при выполнении пишет ошибку "Graph returned an error: Invalid appsecret_proof provided in the API argument".

Токен брал в Graph API Explorer.

```
    <?
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/facebook-sdk/src/Facebook/autoload.php';

$app_id = "{мойAppId}";
$app_secret = "{мойAppSecret}";

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => $app_id,
  'app_secret' => $app_secret,
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.9',
  ]);

$token = '{мойToken}';

$linkData = [
  'link' => 'http://www.example.com',
  'message' => 'User provided message',
  ];

try {
  // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
  $response = $fb->post('/me/feed', $linkData, $token);
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

$graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();

echo 'Posted with id: ' . $graphNode['id'];
```

Помогите исправить ошибку, заранее спасибо.